# Extract complete string containing 'xxx' between two spaces

Tags: arrays, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, re2

I want to know if there is a formula to extract a complete string containing 'xxx' between two spaces.

For example:
[image: example sheet]

Comment: Does it include the brackets? Have you looked at REGEXEXTRACT? https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en

Comment: @GeneralGrievance yes it should include the brackets.

Comment: I don't know for sure without more inputs, but try this one: `=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"\[\S*xxx\S*\]")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A; "\[\S*xxx\S*\]")))
```

[image]